# EditText save String as Integer then multiply it by 3 is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to make a basic conversion tool that i will expand on later. But when i take the information from the EditText and covert it to Integer then try to multiply it, my application crashes on the button click.
          My Java code is as follows, New member to this site, but have been using it for help for weeks now, So thanks you have all helped out so much already

---

```
 package com.example.mayconverter;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Feetyards extends Activity{

EditText feet;
Button convertFeet;
int formula;
TextView displayText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feet_yards);

    displayText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);
    formula = 3;
    convertFeet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFeet);   
    final EditText feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFeet);




    convertFeet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String data = feet.getText().toString();
            final int dataint = Integer.parseInt(data);


            displayText.setText(dataint + formula);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *always* helps to post your LogCat errors, but it looks like you have two problems:

1. You are accidentally creating *two* variables with the same name `feet`:

   This creates a local `feet` variable (not what you want)

   ```
   final EditText feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFeet);
   ```

   Use this instead to initialize your class variable `feet`:

   ```
   feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFeet);
   ```
2. You need to convert your "formula" back into a String:

   ```
   displayText.setText((dataint + formula) + "");
   ```

When you use `setText(Int)`, this tried to load a String value stored in your resources, while `setText(String)` displays the String passed to the function.

Comment: That worked, and added 3 and printed the answer out, but how would i multiply the two. I tried replacing the Addition sign with multiplication signs but no dice. Thank you for the quick reply and hopefully you can help me out with this now lol

Comment: No I set both addition signs to multiplication, i see my error now, thank you A lot for your help, ill probably have more questions soon. Thank you

Comment: No trouble. You can also use `setText(String.valueOf(dataint * formula))`, if you prefer. But since this particular question has been answered please click the checkmark here and ask a new question for your future problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
displayText.setText(dataint + formula);
```

with

```
displayText.setText((dataint + formula)+"");
```